# Multiple instances of web3 to talk to multiple chains

Tags: web3js

I am building an oracle to watch for an event on one chain and respond by sending a transaction to another chain. Creating multiple instances of Web3 (version `1.0.0-beta.26`) is fine but how do I create `Contract` objects with the correct provider? It seems to depend on the `currentProvider` of the last instantiated `Web3` object rather than the `currentProvider` of the `Web3` object used to build create contract object.

Suppose one chain is accessible on port 8546 and the other on 9546. I create two instances for web3:

```
web3a = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');
web3b = new Web3('ws://localhost:9546');
```

But then if I try and get a contract on the `a` chain, it will try and talk to the `b` chain. e.g.

```
const someContract = new web3a.eth.Contract(...)
console.log(someContract.currentProvider.connection.url)
```

will log `ws://localhost:9546`, the `b` connection url rather than the `a` connection that I would expect.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: That's certainly an interesting problem. It _looks_ like it should work. Perhaps raise it as an issue on the web3.js github?

Comment: Good idea. Have posted an issue: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1349